# Extension methods specified as an optional Func<>

Tags: c#, extension-methods

This may be a rather convoluted question, but just checking to see if there is an answer.

Consider there are two extension methods that roughly look like this (and that are in another assembly that I do not have control over):

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string ConversionA<T>(this T self) { /* .... */ }
    public static string ConversionB<T>(this T self) { /* .... */ }
} // eo class ExtensionMethods
```

I have a method which uses this extension method on an object.  I would ideally like the caller to explicitly specify which conversion function to use but default it if necessary, so I hoped I could convert the signature somehow to a `Func<>`:

```
public static class Config
{
    public static T Read<T>(string fileName, Func<T, string> = ExtensionMethods.ConversionA<T>)
    {
    }
} // eo class Config
```

Is this possible at all?  I know it's a long shot :)

Comment: Those are not extension methods, you forgot the `this` keyword (I hesitate to edit, since it might point out a misunderstanding).

Comment: What is wrong with a plain old overload?

Comment: If you are not going to use the extension method syntax, why make them extension methods to begin with?

Comment: I should have added to my post that I do not control these extension methods, they are in another library.  I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible at all?

Sure - the only thing you *can't* do is have the `Func` be an optional parameter.  The default value for an optional parameter must be a compile-time constant.

You *can* do it with an overload, though:

```
public static T Read<T>(string fileName, Func<T, string> func) // non-optional parameter
{
    /* ... */
}

public static T Read<T>(string fileName)
{
    return Read<T>(fileName, ExtensionMethods.ConversionA<T>);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant.  I should have thought of this... :)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Unfortunately I missed the spot where you asked to define a default method. This is **impossible**. C# explicitly disallows assignment of a default parameter for anything that is not a **compile time constant**. Your only way around this will be to set up some overloaded methods, as such:

```
public static T Read<T>(T input)
{
    Read(input, ExtensionMethods.ConversionA<T>);
}

public static T Read<T>(T input, Func<T, string> conversion)
{
    // Logic goes here
}
```

All in all it's not so bad. It's a tiny bit of extra code, and it will get you the behavior you're looking for.

**Original**

It looks like what you have should essentially work. You just need to specify that it accepts a `Func<T, string>`. You can't enforce that it's **always** going to be either `ConversionA<T>` or `ConversionB<T>`, but either of those type signatures should satisfy `Func<T, string>`.

For example (having no idea what your Conversion methods do, I'll make up my own):

```
public static class Conversions
{
    public static string UpperString<T>(T self)
    {
        return self.ToString().ToUpper();
    }

    public static string LowerString<T>(T self)
    {
        return self.ToString().ToLower();
    }
}

public static T Read<T>(T input, Func<T, string> conversion)
{
    // Do-whatchya-do
}

void Main()
{
    Read<SomeObj>(new SomeObj(), Conversions.UpperString<SomeObj>);
    Read<SomeObj>(new SomeObj(), Conversions.LowerString<SomeObj>);
}
```

You'll just need to pass the generic method with the correct type when you eventually call "Read". So you may be required to duplicate type signatures a little bit, but it should work just fine.

That they are extension methods changes nothing. Any extension method can be used in non-extension format explicitly. For example:

```
public static class Extensions 
{
    public static T SomeExtension<T>(this T value) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Can be called in **both** of the following ways:

```
someT.SomeExtension();
Extensions.SomeExtension(someT);
```

Comment: I have edited my post as the signatures were incorrect..  they are extension methods and therefore they have `this T self`.

Comment: Absolutely, but I wish to provide a default extension method.  I understand they can be called directly as they are regular methods.  I have edited the title to clarify.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Ah, I missed that. Answer is updated. You can't define a default parameter for anything that isn't a compile-time constant. You'll need to create an overload that accepts no second parameter and call the full method with the default you want.